# How To Implement Authentication System With a JWT Without Expiration

Tags: node.js, typescript, authentication, security, jwt

I was wondering how it could be implemented an authentication system based on JWT where these don't have an explicit expiration date

- How can be handled the force "expiration"?
- Is it possibile without state/session management?
- Is this even correct?

Edit: I'm perfectly aware about how to implement an "infinite" jwt technically, and what are the implications, I understand perfectly the refresh token system as well,

I want to know how to design a system with this kind of behaviour and keep it secure, giving the capability to expire the tokens for example after an user changes his password, or other possible behaviours

Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: The idea of a jwt token is that it needs to be refreshed. Otherwise, someone could intercept your token and use it indefinitly. Using a JWT token might not be the best choice, for what you are trying to do. Maybe a good old API key would work ?